# How do I turn off the Examine Dashboard?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

When I go to the Developer section in the backoffice these two rest services are kicked off...

```
/umbraco/BackOffice/Api/ExamineManagementApi/GetIndexerDetails?_=1412628951557
/umbraco/BackOffice/Api/ExamineManagementApi/GetSearcherDetails?_=1412628951560
```

These seem to be populating the examine management dashboard with their stats, but I have a large number of nodes on my site so this causes the browser to hang/freeze.

Is there a way to turn off, or lazy load the examine dashboard?

Comment: Have you raised this as an issue with umbraco.org? If you haven't then you should and see what their response is.

Comment: @Digbyswift Yes I have a open question here. http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/57168-622-Examine-Management-dashboard-hangsbrowser-freeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Dashboard.config` there is a `ExamineManagement` section. I removed this section and now the developer section doesn't hang anymore. I think a better way is to have this section lazy-load but this works for now.

```
<section alias="ExamineManagement">
    <areas>
      <area>developer</area>
    </areas>
    <tab caption="Examine Management">
      <control>/umbraco/dashboard/ExamineManagement.ascx</control>
    </tab>
</section>
```